# Pass a parameter to js function in different page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, c#-2.0

I have an aspx page with a drop down list. When a selction is made, I need to pass the selected value to a javascript function in a different page. This second page is displaying a map using javascript:

```
<script>
    var map;
    var ServiceName = "http://some_url//this_is_dynamic_part/MapServer
    ....
</script>
```

so, from page1.aspx, I need to open this page in a new window and pass a parameter (i.e. drop down's selected value) to replace "this_is_dynamic_part" of variable ServiceName.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a query parameter here.  In the selection handler, when building the URL that you will pass to `window.open()`, append `?key=value`, where `value` is the value you want to pass and `key` is some parameter name (anything you like).

Then your second page can refer to the value of the page parameters in `location.search`.

Comment: I used the answer(s) in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values. I passed a query string to second page (Response.Redirect("secondpage.html?cid=abcd", where "abcd" is the drop down list's selected value); added a function in secondpage.html to pasre/get query string value and set "this_is_dynamic_part" variable's value to value in query string ("abcd").